# insert in database that is not the default DJANGO

Tags: python, mysql, django

I know django works with multiple database connections, I need to insert in a database that is not the default, but I get the following error.

```
ProgrammingError at /api-jde/f59presapi/2279/
(1146, 'Table \'dblocal."oracle"."FPRES"\' doesn\'t exist')
```

this is the configuration of my settings.py file

```
DATABASES = {
   'default': {
       'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
       'NAME': 'dblocal',
       'USER': 'root',
       'PASSWORD': '',
       'HOST': '',
       'PORT': '',
   },
   'bd2': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.oracle',
        'NAME': 'XXXX',
        'USER': 'oracle',
        'PASSWORD': 'xxxxx',
    },

}
```

the bd in which I need to insert is the db2 (I'm not putting all the data here but if I have them full), in the created model I have the METa configuration with the following:

```
class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = u'"oracle"."FPRES"'
```

Answer (score 0):

`db = DATABASES['db2']`

Perhaps this will help if added to the meta class.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can't specify a database for a specific model. You need to do something like this every time:

```
YourModel.objects.using('bd2').all()
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am working with Rest-Frameword and in the queryset I indicate how you tell me with the use but still the error continues.